# Model isn't populating with data when the collection is called. Backbone and Django-Tastypie

Tags: django, backbone.js, backbone-views, tastypie

I'm having trouble seeing why models aren't showing up when my collection view instantiates. The array is called, and when I call `notes.models` I get the right number of records. But, the `console.log(note)` is supposed to be called, nothing happens. So, the fetch seems to be working, and there is data, I can see it in the response, it's just not being passed into the `collection.each` view. Any help is welcome. Here's everything.

The TastpieCollection and TasttypieModel come from http://paltman.com/2012/04/30/integration-backbonejs-tastypie/ which seems to work really well.

```
$(function() {

    // Note: The model and collection are extended from TastypieModel and TastypieCollection
    // to handle the parsing and URLs

    window.Note = TastypieModel.extend({});

    window.Notes = TastypieCollection.extend({
        model: Note,
        url: NOTES_API_URL
    });

    // starts by assigning the collection to a variable so that it can load the collection
    window.notes = new Notes();

    window.NoteView = Backbone.View.extend({

        className: "panel panel-default note",
        template: _.template($('#notes-item').html()),

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    window.NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        id: "notes-block",
        className: "panel panel-info",
        template: _.template($('#notes-item-list').html()),

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection.bind('change', this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            this.collection.each(function(note){
                //var view = new NoteView({ model: note });
                console.log(note);
                //$('#notes-list').append(view.render().el);
            });
            console.log('done');
            return this;
        }
    });

    window.NotesRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "list",
            'blank': 'blank'
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.notesView = new NoteListView({
                collection: window.notes
            });
            notes.fetch();
        },
        list: function () {
            $('#app').empty();
            $('#app').append(this.notesView.render().el);
            console.log(notes.length);
        },
        blank: function() {
            $('#app').empty();
            $('#app').text('Another view');
        }
    });

    window.notesRouter = new NotesRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the `fetch` (which is an AJAX call) has returned from the server before you try to `this.collection.each`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I moved the notes.fetch to a bunch of different locations. No change. And just to check, I removed the fetch, so it's not calling anything and there is nothing in notes.models. So the fetch is working.

Comment: Try using `console.log(this.collection.toJSON())`, `console.log` puts live references in the console so what you see in the console is not necessarily what was there when `console.log` was called.

Comment: It's not even getting into that loop. There is not return from the loop.

Comment: You don't call `render` on your `NoteListView` anywhere? The call is right there in your router's `list` method.

Comment: The render is called. And that template is rendered just fine. But the bit from NoteListView that loops trough the collection with teh .each and renders a view for each model in the collection is what's not working.

Comment: `this.collection.each` doesn't do anything because the collection is empty. Throw a `console.log(this.collection.toJSON())` *before* the `each` and you'll see that the collection is empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39533/discussion-between-dave-merwin-and-mu-is-too-short)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it is working. It's not working they way I want, but the code above does work. So I'm going to ask this question in a different way to get to the heart of the issue.